# Upload only files with no extension in filename

Tags: amazon-s3, aws-cli

I would like to execute `aws s3 sync . s3://<some bucket>` and use the `--exclude` flag to exclude all files with an extension in the filename and change the `content-type`.

Tried this but does not work. Still finds files with extension.

`/usr/bin/aws s3 sync /home/www s3://<bucket name> --dryrun --exclude "*.*" --include "*" --content-type text/html`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You just need to use `--exclude` to exclude files with extensions

```
aws s3 sync --exclude "*.*" --content-type="text/html" . s3://hernan-test-bucket/
```

Example execution:

```
:~# ls
file1  file2  file3.txt  file4.txt

:~# aws s3 sync --exclude "*.*" --content-type="text/html" . s3://bucket/
upload: ./file1 to s3://bucket/file1
upload: ./file2 to s3://bucket/file2
```

Comment: Sorry. I updated the description. I want to upload files that have no extension and change its content-type to be `text/html`